# Docker - Error: EEXIST: file already exists, symlink

Tags: docker, apostrophe-cms

I have developed a small **"proof of concept"** ApostropheCMS application.  The application runs fine with `node app.js`.  I'm trying to build and deploy with **Docker** for Windows on Windows 7 with **Oracle VM VirtualBox** following this [tutorial](https://apostrophecms.org/docs/tutorials/howtos/docker.html).

I am able to deploy the **mongo image**.  I am able to build my application image using the default Dockerfile.   When I attempt to run my application, docker image linked with the mongo image I receive the following error:

> $ docker run --link=ato-home-db:mongodb -p 3000:3000 ato-home-webapp
>
> ato-home-webapp@2.0.0 start /app node app.js fs.js:1014   return
>   binding.symlink(preprocessSymlinkDestination(target, type, path),
>                    ^ Error: EEXIST: file already exists, symlink '/app/node_modules/apostrophe/lib/modules/apostrophe-assets/public' ->
>   '/app/public/modules/apostrophe-assets'
>       at Object.fs.symlinkSync (fs.js:1014:18)
>       at Object.self.linkAssetFolderOnUnix (/app/node_modules/apostrophe/lib/modules/apostrophe-assets/index.js:646:10)
>       at Object.self.linkAssetFolder (/app/node_modules/apostrophe/lib/modules/apostrophe-assets/index.js:612:14)
>       at /app/node_modules/apostrophe/lib/modules/apostrophe-assets/index.js:578:14
>       at /app/node_modules/@sailshq/lodash/lib/index.js:3253:15
>       at baseForOwn (/app/node_modules/@sailshq/lodash/lib/index.js:2223:14)
>       at /app/node_modules/@sailshq/lodash/lib/index.js:3223:18
>       at Function. (/app/node_modules/@sailshq/lodash/lib/index.js:3526:13)
>       at self.symlinkModules (/app/node_modules/apostrophe/lib/modules/apostrophe-assets/index.js:574:9)
>       at /app/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:718:13
>       at iterate (/app/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:262:13)
>       at async.forEachOfSeries.async.eachOfSeries (/app/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:281:9)
>       at _parallel (/app/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:717:9)
>       at Object.async.series (/app/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:739:9)
>       at Object.self.afterInit (/app/node_modules/apostrophe/lib/modules/apostrophe-assets/index.js:521:20)
>       at invoke (/app/node_modules/apostrophe/index.js:423:23) npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 1 npm ERR! ato-home-webapp@2.0.0 start:
>   `node app.js` npm ERR! Exit status 1 npm ERR! npm ERR! Failed at the
>   ato-home-webapp@2.0.0 start script. npm ERR! This is probably not a
>   problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
>   /root/.npm/_logs/2018-08-07T00_15_24_396Z-debug.log

I'm hoping for a possible solution or suggestions for **ApostropheCMS tutorials** or **"How Tos"** to get past this roadblock.

I am new to ApostropheCMS and Docker.   Any input would be greatly appreciated.  I can supply additional information if helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that you're building your image on Windows (to a Linux container). Please try rebuilding your image in a Unix environment.